# Is it possible to insert a "sub" label into a BasicBlock in LLVM?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

Suppose I've a BasicBlock with label, e.g., `entry`.

Now, I would like to insert a "sub" label into this BasicBlock without breaking up the block into two parts.

In assembly, it would look like:

```
entry:
...
.mylabel1:
...
.mylabel2:
...
```

Is it possible to insert labels into a BasicBlock to divide it into "parts", but without splitting the block?

Comment: Well, you can just do unconditional jump to another BB part (making it a distinct BB, ofc).

Answer (score 1):

No.

By definition, a basic block only has one entry point, and that's how it's implemented in LLVM. A label is an entry point, so what you're asking for is not possible.